# Is there a better way to enumarate a list within a list?

Tags: python, enumerate

I need to insert a item representing an index value for each list within a list.

So, I have this:

```
 cfgs = [
         ['pppoe', '1001', 'jon', 'jon123'],
         ['pppoe', '2000', 'joe', 'joe123'],
         ['dhcp', '1001'], ['dhcp', '1000'],
         ['static', '1010', '192.168.2.40', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.2.1', '8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4'],
         ['sfu', '1001', 'untagged'],
         ['hgu', '1001']
    ]

index = 0
for line in cfgs:
    line = line.insert(0, str(index))
    index += 1

print(cfgs)
```

And the output is working as intended and is exactly what I need:

```
[['0', 'pppoe', '1001', 'jon', 'jon123'], ['1', 'pppoe', '2000', 'joe', 'joe123'], ['2', 'dhcp', '1001'], ['3', 'dhcp', '1000'], ['4', 'static', '1010', '192.168.2.40', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.2.1', '8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4'], ... ]
```

My question: Is there a better or more pythonic way to do that? Like using list comprehension and enumerate?

I tried that in place of `for` loop:

```
cfgs = [list(enumerate(line)) for line in cfgs]
```

But didn't work as I expected.

```
[[(0, 'pppoe'), (1, '1001'), (2, 'jon'), (3, 'jon123')], [(0, 'pppoe'), (1, '2000'), (2, 'joe'), (3, 'joe123')],...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the `for` loop, but use `enumerate()` there.

```
for index, line in enumerate(cfgs):
    line.insert(0, str(index))
```

There's also no need to assign the result of `line.insert`. It doesn't return anything, it just modifies the list in place, and assigning to `line` doesn't do anything useful since the variable is never used after that.

If you want a list comprehension, you can add lists to concatenate them:

```
[[index] + line for index, line in enumerate(cfgs)]
```

But I don't think `[index] + line` is very clear.